# How do I replace initial (first or last) with a name from another column?

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

How do I replace initials with full names (if the initial matches the full name in another column)?

I have data that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(name = c("Acorus americanus", "Nothocalais cuspidata", "Elymus repens", "Elymus hmmmm", "Acorus americanus"),
                   synonym = c("A. calamus", "Agoseris cuspidata", "Agropyron r.", "Elymus sp.", "S. americanus"))

                   name            synonym
1     Acorus americanus         A. calamus
2 Nothocalais cuspidata Agoseris cuspidata
3         Elymus repens       Agropyron r.
4          Elymus hmmmm         Elymus sp.
5     Acorus americanus      S. americanus
```

How can I replace the initial with the name, so I get this?

```
                   name            synonym
1     Acorus americanus     Acorus calamus
2 Nothocalais cuspidata Agoseris cuspidata
3         Elymus repens   Agropyron repens 
4          Elymus hmmmm         Elymus sp.
5     Acorus americanus      S. americanus
```

There are also other abbreviations like `sp.`, `var.` and `ssp.` that I don't want to change into names, but none of them are single letters. Also I would like to leave the initial if it doesn't match the first letter of a name in another column.

Comment: Please add these other exceptions to your example to make sure solutions will meet your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solutions tests for a shared first letter using `stringr::str_extract()`, then replaces single-letter abbreviations using `stringr::str_replace()`. (You could also use base `grep()` and `gsub()`).

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(
    synonym = if_else(
      str_extract(synonym, "^\\w") == str_extract(name, "^\\w"),
      str_replace(
        synonym,
        "^\\w\\.", 
        str_extract(name, "^\\w+")
      ),
      synonym
    ),
    synonym = if_else(
      str_extract(synonym, "(?<=\\s)\\w") == str_extract(name, "(?<=\\s)\\w"),
      str_replace(
        synonym,
        "\\w\\.$", 
        str_extract(name, "\\w+$")
      ),
    synonym
    )
  )
```

```
                   name            synonym
1     Acorus americanus     Acorus calamus
2 Nothocalais cuspidata Agoseris cuspidata
3         Elymus repens   Agropyron repens
4          Elymus hmmmm         Elymus sp.
5     Acorus americanus      S. americanus
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  summarise(read.table(text=t(cur_data())))%>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~if_else(str_detect(lag(., def=""), .), lag(.), .)))%>%
  unite(result, sep = ' ')%>%
  mutate(rep(names(data), nrow(data)))%>%
  unstack()
 
                  name            synonym
1     Acorus americanus     Acorus calamus
2 Nothocalais cuspidata Agoseris cuspidata
3         Elymus repens   Agropyron repens
4          Elymus hmmmm         Elymus sp.
5     Acorus americanus      S. americanus
```